# Jmeter Constant Timer with dynamic parameter

Tags: jmeter

I want to use HTTP request with timer.

Thread Group Config
[image]

CSV Data Set Config 
[image]

HTTP Request work without timer. When I add a Constant Timer everything works but Constant Timer doesn't with delay time. I set Thread Delay 5000. 
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

By default JMeter **does NOT include** the time, taken by [PreProcessors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors), [PostProcessors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and [Timers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) into Sample Result so you will not be able to see it anywhere unless you put your request under [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) and tick both boxes, to wit:

- Generate parent sample
- Include duration of timer and pre-post processors in generated sample

[image: JMeter Duration of timers, pre post processors transaction controller]

Once done you should see that your sampler duration should be increased by the amount of time you specify in the Constant Timer